# JSM 2013 mixer?

Tags: discussion

Should we guys try to arrange a meeting on the JSM 2013? It's the business meeting requests time now through March, I believe. (Sorry for the North American bias here, but this is the biggest statistical conference in the world, so I am sure plenty of CV folks will be there.)

As far as I am concerned, if all the mixers and business meetings go as they have for the last five years, I personally will have a full evening program every day from Monday to Wednesday, and I am not yet factoring in the dinners that will certainly get themselves arranged with all the professional friends that I only meet there.

**Update**: JSM 2013 is basically around the corner. If nobody requested the time for a formal mixer, so be it.

Comment: If any of you are on the fence about attending, please consider applying for a Stack Exchange sponsorship! The procedure for doing so can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conference/132283#132283

Comment: @Aarthi, so does the post need to be on CV Meta or on SO Meta? I'd be happy to provide all the info you need.

Comment: Yes, in CV meta! :)

Comment: @Aaarthi, done: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/jsm2013-sponsorship-proposal

Comment: Guys, let's close this one. Or may be even delete it, since the other post I linked to is more appropriate.

Comment: Actually they have different purposes -- this one is to organize a meetup, that one is to garner support for SE to sponsor your attendance. Unless we've had a big misunderstanding?

Comment: May be; nobody's responding to this one though.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes time -- plus, this is in August, and registration doesn't open until May. It might be that a lot of people aren't certain of their attendance yet.

Comment: Registration is open now for presenters. In fact, the presentation abstract needs to be submitted by the end of the week. So if anybody is contemplating going, they should make their minds in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to give this a bump to see what people's plans are.

I'm not attending JSM this year, but I am currently working in Montreal.  I imagine people are busy with the usual conference stuff (the actual sessions as well as the networking/catching up/frantically revising presentations the night before/etc), but if anyone wants to meet up for coffee or a beer or what-have-you, it'd be nice to meet people face-to-face.