# JSM 2015 mixer?

Tags: discussion

I've asked on the CV Meta [before](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1950/5739) about who is attending the Joint Statistical Meetings, and who wants to match the usernames and faces. Honestly, I am jumping from session to session during the day, and then from a business meeting to a reception in the evening. But I thought I'd bring this up again for the benefit of the community.

Propose time and place to meet up as an answer. Comment if you are coming.

Comment: I am coming, I am there from Friday late night to all of Thursday.

Comment: OK, it looks like there are about 10 people, but they will prefer to stay anonymous. Fair enough :)

Comment: Hey, who was it who bumped into me last night??? Did not catch your name!!!

Comment: I didn't make the JSM this year & am sorry I missed a chance to visit Seattle. Were there one or two presentations you attended that stood above the rest?

Comment: A short course on communication and soft skills was the best JSM event over the past few years of my attendance. I work in industry, I need to come to mutually understood agreements with other members of my team and the clients regarding the work to be done. I was terrified to see how consulting statisticians in academia are being tossed around. A couple of technical ideas in my field that I will take home on multiple imputation and disclosure protection, too. The coolest presentations were happening elsewhere if you look at https://twitter.com/hashtag/jsm2015.